# set-cookies not null but cookiecontainer empty

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest

After logged in, cookies are generated for subsequent requests.

I am trying to get cookies by sending a "POST" request.

In the response header, there is a "set-cookies" field and its value is like: "value1=value1,value2=value2......";

However, the CookieContainer i created for the HttpWebRequest is still empty.

So what is happening and how can I have my CookieContainer filled?

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

```
string loginData = "################################";
            CookieContainer cookiecontainer = new CookieContainer();
            HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.ftwilliam.com/cgi-bin/Enter.cgi");
            myRequest.CookieContainer = cookiecontainer;                
            myRequest.Method = "POST";
            myRequest.KeepAlive = true;
            myRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
            myRequest.Referer = "https://www.ftwilliam.com/cgi-bin/Enter.cgi";
            myRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:26.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/26.0";
            myRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
            byte[] loginDataBytes = encoding.GetBytes(loginData);
            myRequest.ContentLength = loginDataBytes.Length;
            Stream stream = myRequest.GetRequestStream();
            stream.Write(loginDataBytes, 0, loginDataBytes.Length);
            stream.Close();
            HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse)myRequest.GetResponse();
```